# is there a way to accept all image mime types in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

i would like to accept only images to be stored however i have to specify every image extension,
is there a single line code like in other languages like java and PHP where i use `image/*`

here is the code requiring me to put every file extension in node

```js
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        //store image
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like you could simply check that `file.mimetype` *starts with* `image/`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (file.mimetype.match(/^image/))
```

or

```
if (file.mimetype.indexOf('image/') > -1)
```

or

```
if (file.mimetype.substr(0,6) == 'image/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a regex to match `images/*` only:

```
const imagesMimeRegex = new RegExp("image/(.*)");

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(imagesMimeRegex.test(file.mimetype)){
        // do something
    }
};
```